# Python - DBF Schema Extraction - 10 Character Limit for Field Names

Tags: python, dbf

I'm trying to get around the 10 character limit for field names when converting from a DBF. I have tried several different libraries (dbf and dbfimport) with no luck. I'm not sure if it's even possible.

**Example:**

```
Original
Field 1 = percentage
Field 2 = percentage_all

Converts to
Field 1 = percentage
Field 2 = percentag2
```

**Code:**

```
import dbf
import os, sys, collections

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

path = r""

for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(('.dbf', '.DBF')):
            dbflocation = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, file)).lower()
            print dbflocation
            try:
                tbl = dbf.structure(dbflocation)
                print tbl

                for field in tbl:
                    print field

            except Exception, e:
                print Exception
                print e
                continue
```

Comment: The code you are showing is displaying already created dbf files, with already shortened names -- what program is actually creating the dbf files to begin with?

Comment: It's foxpro and uses container files to assist with field names. When reading directly from foxpro, the names export as desired but it seems that the .dbc files are unknown to the library therefore it's not possible?

Comment: Ah.  I never had a need to support `.dbc` files for my work.  If you send me the matching `.dbc` and `.dbf` files I'll see if I can easily add that support to my `dbf` library.

Comment: Sure, I'll need to do some formatting and get you a sample as there is some data we wouldn't want to send as part of some of the field names.